# Using target values in both (X and y) arguments of fit(X, y)

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

This question is based on [SQL Server Machine Learning Services Ski Rental tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/python-ski-rental-linear-regression?view=sql-server-ver15).

We have a dataframe `df`:

```
index Year  Month  Day  RentalCount  WeekDay  Holiday  Snow
0     2014      1   20          445        2        1     0
1     2014      2   13           40        5        0     0
2     2013      3   10          456        1        0     0
3     2014      3   31           38        2        0     0
4     2014      4   24           23        5        0     0
..     ...    ...  ...          ...      ...      ...   ...
448   2013      2   19           57        3        0     1
449   2015      3   18           26        4        0     0
450   2015      3   24           29        3        0     1
451   2014      3   26           50        4        0     1
452   2015     12    6          377        1        0     1

[453 rows x 7 columns]
```

We want to predict RentalCount:

```
# Store the variable we'll be predicting on.
target = "RentalCount"

# Generate the training set.  Set random_state to be able to replicate results.
train = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)

# Select anything not in the training set and put it in the testing set.
test = df.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]

# Initialize the model class.
lin_model = LinearRegression()

# Fit the model to the training data.
lin_model.fit(train[columns], train[target])
```

In the tutorial, columns are `['Month', 'Day', 'RentalCount', 'Weekday', 'Holiday', 'Snow']` (everything except `Year`).

This means that both arguments of `lin_model.fit(train[columns], train[target])` will contain the `'RentalCount'` values. Since it is the target variable, shouldn't it **only** be included in the target (2nd) argument?

With:

```
lin_predictions = lin_model.predict(test[columns])

lin_mse = mean_squared_error(lin_predictions, test[target])
print(lin_mse)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(test[target],lin_predictions)
```

I can see that mse is low, and r2 high (`1.63e-27` and `1.0`), but is this correct?

I tried removing RentalCount from columns, but I only get worse scores (`35003.54` and
`0.224`)

[Notebook with data](https://deepnote.com/workspace/test-07a9-b4207c8f-8479-4556-981c-5a8ce47df3f1/project/Untitled-project-801faf26-ba93-4165-bf75-b5793ded87c2/%2Fsql%20server%20ML%20services%20tutorial.ipynb)

Comment: As you've discovered, it's trivially easy to predict `y` when you use `y` as a feature! This is just a particularly unfortunate bug in the code you're reviewing.

Comment: It came to my mind at some point that it could be a bug, but I'm not an expert, so I had to ask. Thanks!